Phantom Wallet official CRX backup link used for phantom/synpress test automation project stopped working
I am using my own fork of https://github.com/phantom/synpress to create e2e automation for a Solana app. The key thing here is that Phantom team (most probably) has provided a CRX link of Phantom wallet's latest version which enabled to install the phantom wallet as a test setup inside the test automation browser via this link https://crx-backup.phantom.dev/latest.crx. The link has stopped working for more than 2 weeks now, and I really wonder if we can have a stable phantom wallet official CRX link from Phantom to enable E2E test automation using Synpress library. Thanks!  My fork for the reference: https://github.com/DavitMkhitaryan/synpress-solana
